# MYSQL : list all occurrences of duplicates in a table

Tags: mysql, duplicates, group-concat

I want to list all occurrences of duplicates in a table and regroup them by their id.

Here is my table :

```
+------------+----+
| name       | id |
+------------+----+
| Produit 78 |  5 |
| Produit 78 |  6 |
| Produit 78 | 11 |
| Produit 69 | 12 |
| Produit 12 | 14 |
| Produit 12 | 15 |
| Produit 92 | 22 |
| Produit 92 | 25 |
```

I've tried this :

```
select name, id from commande_ligne group by name having count(name) > 1;
```

But it only list me the duplicate with their first occurrence.

Whereas I would like something like this :

```
+------------+-------+
| name       | id    |
+------------+-------+
| Produit 78 | 5,6,11|
| Produit 12 | 14,15 |
| Produit 92 | 22,25 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the values of `id` among the duplicates, you can do it this way:

```
select name, GROUP_CONCAT(id) 
from commande_ligne 
group by name having count(name) > 1;
```

Read more about the [GROUP_CONCAT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should separate the name and the number into different attributes:

```
name | number | id
```

and the SQL query should be something like this:

```
select ... 
group by name, number;
```

depending on what you want to do.

Is something like this?

Comment: I would like a column that lists the ids of the associated name.

Comment: like a  pivot table where the product name is the column name, instead of [NAME]? is that what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

With the data sample provided with name as Product 78 with an Id, the result you looking for cannot be achieved because under the Unique ID there is always one Product 78 with a unique ID, so that cannot be grouped by IDs, however, you can group by Name for the different ID for grouped records by name for Product 78 it will show the Ids 5,6,11 that's when grouped by Field Name

Comment: And how can i group them by Name for the different id for grouped records by name please